# Vuex getter for filter not updating after mutating array of state

Tags: arrays, vue.js, state, vuex, getter

I'm building a todo app. There is a button to toggle the checked/completed state of all todos. I'm mutating an array of the `state`, but the `getters` are not being updating. When I click `toggle complete` button, the database and the array `state.todos` update, but the `$store.getters.filteredTodos` does not update.

So the some todos are displayed incorrectly (some are checked and others are not when all should be checked or unchecked)

```
    // in getters
    filteredTodos(state) {
        if (state.filter == 'active') {
            return state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
        }

        if (state.filter == 'completed') {
            return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed);
        }

        return state.todos;
    },

    // in mutations
    retrieveTodos(state, todos) {
        Vue.set(state, 'todos', todos);

        // tried the following, but also didn't work
        //state.todos.splice(0, state.todos.length, ...todos);
    },

    // in actions
    toggleCompleted(context, completed) {
        axios.patch('/todos/toggle-completed', {completed})
            // response.data is the array of the updated todo items
            .then(response => context.commit('retrieveTodos', response.data))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
    },
```

From several posts here in StackOverflow and in VueForum, I have seen the same solution:

```
        Vue.set(state, 'todos', todos);
        // or
        state.todos.splice(0, state.todos.length, ...todos);
```

None of them worked. The `$store.state` updates, but the `$store.getters.filteredTodos` does not.

How to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I'm following [this tutorial series on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEhEHUEU3x5q-xB1On4CsLPts0-rZ9oos) to get started with Vue, but I'm doing somethings on my own. In the tutorial, the guy creates the Vue project for the fronend and a Laravel project for the backend. I did the same.

- [My GitHub repo for the frontend](https://github.com/AndreSouzaAbreu/vue-todo-app)
- [My GitHub repo for the backend](https://github.com/AndreSouzaAbreu/vue-todo-app-backend)

Comment: In your mutation, wouldn't simply doing `state.todos = todos` work? Also, when you're displaying your todos, I'm assuming you're looping with `v-for`. What `:key` value are you using?

Comment: I did this. I initially wrote ``state.todos = todos``, but it also did not update the getter functions. It works only to update the ``state``, but I need to update the ``filteredTodos`` as well. The ``:key`` is equal to the todo's id.

Comment: Could you possibly reproduce this and share a link via https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Yes. I edited the questions. Please look at it. You can git clone my repos to simulate the problem

Comment: I discovered what was the error The getter were updating correctly, but what was not updating was the TodoItem component. I found a solution and will post it here later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem had nothing to do with `getters` or `state`. Both were being updated correctly in the three ways that I tried.

The problem was in the `Todo` component. Previously, the code was something like this:

```
// in the template 
        <label class="todo-action" :for="`todo-checked-${id}`">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="completed" 
                   :id="`todo-checked-${id}`" @change="update">
        </label>

        <div class="todo-title">
            {{title}}
        </div>

// inside script tag
    data() {
        // this allow me to access this.id, this.completed, and this.title 
        // instead of this.todo.id, this.todo.completed, and this.todo.title
        return this.todo;
    },
```

The problem is that `data` was not being updated. I fixed it as follows

```
// in the template I access the props from the todo item, so it is always up to date
        <label class="todo-action" :for="`todo-checked-${todo.id}`">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed" 
                   :id="`todo-checked-${todo.id}`" @change="update">
        </label>

        <div class="todo-title">
            {{todo.title}}
        </div>
```

Yeah, it was a very simple solution